# Default value for a photo in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i'm trying to make a function that allows everyone to publish whatever they want but when the visitor is not a user his post photo's default will be a photo from my directory storage that holds the meaning of anonymous or something alike:

what is the SQL command line that allows me to do so?

My post migration table is:

```
   Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
         $table->string('title');
          $table->string('username');
         $table->string('body');
         $table->boolean('valid')->default(0);
          $table->string('photo',150)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
    });
```

My function store() is the following:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {

   $post= new Post();
   $post->title=$request->input('title');
   $post->photo=$request->photo; //what do i change in this field?
   $post->username=$request->input('username');
      $post->body=$request->input('body');
   $post->save();
   return redirect ('/ed');
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
    $postPhoto = $request->photo
} else{
    //photo from directory storage 
    $postPhoto = public_path('/images/default.jpg'); 
}

// store photo in the database

$post->photo = $postPhoto;
```

Comment: Hi, public function store(Request $request)  {

   $post= new Post();
   $post->title = $request->input('title');

    if (Auth::check()) {
   
    $postPhoto = Auth::user()->photo;
    $emailpost = Auth::user()->email;

} else {

    $postPhoto = public_path('/images/def.jpg');
    $emailpost = $request->input('username');
}

     $post->photo = $postPhoto;
     $post->username = $emailpost;

      $post->body = $request->input('body');
   $post->save();

   return redirect ('/ed');
}

Comment: this is the error i get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: That is a syntactic error you can solve it :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@Wellwisher is right! But you can also set a default value to the photo field at posts table (and that is if you not planning to change the image name).

```
$table->string('photo', 150)->default('avatar.jpg');
```

and you will overwrite (change) it in case user uploads a new image as his/her profile image.